# How do I retrieve value from mysql database into the infowindow in google map?

Tags: php, javascript, database, google-maps

How do I retrieve value from mysql database and display in infowindow according to the markers?

Example first marker, info window should show "A"..For now, it shows everything. How do I do this? Please guide me through. Thanks!

```
<script>
        var map;
        var marker;
        var infowindow;

        var info = <?php echo json_encode($infoWindow); ?>;
        var placeX= <?php echo json_encode($getX); ?>;
        var placeY= <?php echo json_encode($getY); ?>;

        function initialize()
        {
            var mapProp = {
              center:new google.maps.LatLng(1.35208,103.81984),
              zoom:11,
              mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

            for(var x=0; x<placeX.length; x++)
            {
                retrieve(placeX[x],placeY[x],info[x])
            }   

        }

        function retrieve(x,y,i)
        {
            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
              position:new google.maps.LatLng(y,x),
              });

            marker.setMap(map);

            marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png')



            marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow ({content: '<b>No. of people who choose this location:</b> '+ info});
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',function(){
                marker.info.open(map,marker);
                });

        }

        function addInfoWindow(x,y,h) 
        {
           var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content:"Hello World!"
              });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell by just looking at the information you provided. Do you know how to use a mysql database with php? And how's the data stored on your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument for `retrieve` that contains the info is `i` not `info`

```
marker.info = new google.maps
.InfoWindow ({content: '<b>No. of people who choose this location:</b> '+ i});
//------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

---

**Related to the comments:**(apply a different marker for the highest values)

Put this right after  `var info = <?php echo json_encode($infoWindow); ?>;`

---

```
max=Math.max.apply(null,info);
```

it will define a variable max with the highest item of info as value.

Now you can use this value for a conditional marker:

```
marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/'+
                  ((i==max)?'red':'‌​green')+'-dot.png');
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help! Finally it worked after figuring it out for hours. Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask if there's any way to change the marker's colour example: No. of people who choose this location: 3 (highest number), the marker's color will change to red.

Comment: When the info only contains the number, this should work:`marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/'+((i==3)?'red':'green')+'-dot.png');`

Comment: Yup it only contains number but it will always be dynamic. Therefore, is not always 3.

Comment: And what's the dynamic condition, where does it come from? Do you want to mark the highest value of all markers with a red marker?

Comment: Yup. I want to mark the marker with a red marker for the highest value.

Comment: It's not difficult, see my edited post.